# Molecule and ligation finding program

Tags: python, performance, beginner, calculator, bioinformatics

I wrote this code so I could figure out the number of molecules within a plasmid and an insert of DNA. I then get the amount of insert DNA I would need to use (in uL) for a ligation with the DNA at different insert ratios and dilutions.

How can I clean up this code? It works correctly. However, I feel like I typed this out all the extremely long way and I would love to know how to make this more performant.

In my next project I would like to not have to type all of these out. I imagine that I am missing some functions or loops. I am still a very new beginner and this is my first project outside of a classroom.

```
print "Please put the amount of BPs: "
number = int(raw_input())
solution = (number * 660)
Avo = (6.022 * (10 ** 23))
Grams_Avo = ( solution / Avo)
print "Put in Concentration (ng/ul): "
conc = float(raw_input())
multiple = (10 ** -9)
amount = (conc * multiple)
total = float(amount / Grams_Avo)
print "Amount of molecules:  %s" % total


print "Amount of ul used by the plasmid: "
plasmid = float(raw_input())
particles = float(plasmid * total)
print "What ratio amount will you use?: "
ratio = int(raw_input())
molecules_needed = float(particles * ratio)
print molecules_needed


print "Conc. of your oligo?: "
oligo = float(raw_input())
oligo_num = float(oligo * multiple) # amount 
print "Enter number of G in Oligo: "
G = int(raw_input())
print "Enter number of A in Oligo: "
A = int(raw_input())
print "Enter number of T in Oligo: "
T = int(raw_input())
print "Enter number of C in Oligo: "
C = int(raw_input())
sumG = (G * 329)
sumA = (A * 313)
sumT = (T * 304)
sumC = (C * 289)
daoligo = (sumG + sumA + sumT + sumC) # g/mol

print "Total amount of your insert %s" % daoligo

oligototal = float(oligo_num / (daoligo/Avo)) # molecules for insert
complete = float(molecules_needed/oligototal) #amount of insert needed from stock ul

print "What dilution will you use?"
print "1. Stock"
print "2. 1:10"
print "3. 1:20"
print "4. 1:30"
print "5. 1:50"
code = float(raw_input())
if code == 1:
    print complete #stock
elif code == 2:
    code2 = (oligototal/10)
    complete1 = float(molecules_needed/code2)
    print complete1 #1:10
elif code == 3:
    code3 (oligototal/20)
    complete2 = float(molecules_needed/code3)
    print complete2 #1:20
elif code == 4:
    code4 = (oligototal/30)
    complete3 = float(molecules_needed/code4)
    print complete3 #1:30
elif code == 5:
    code_5 = (oligototal/50)
    complete4 = float(molecules_needed/code_5)
    print complete4 #1:50
```

Answer (score 1):

For the starter, you can create small function which will get input since your code requires too much user input.

Just making that one function will reduce repetitive code of `raw_input()` and printing it's msg.

Also, your code will be more readable.

**Code:**

```
def get_input(msg):
    print msg
    val = int(raw_input())
    return val

number = get_input("Please put the amount of BPs: ")

solution = (number * 660)
Avo = (6.022 * (10 ** 23))
Grams_Avo = ( solution / Avo)

conc = float(get_input("Put in Concentration (ng/ul): "))

multiple = (10 ** -9)
amount = (conc * multiple)
total = float(amount / Grams_Avo)
print "Amount of molecules:  %s" % total

plasmid = float(get_input("Amount of ul used by the plasmid: "))
particles = float(plasmid * total)

ratio = get_input("What ratio amount will you use?: ")

molecules_needed = float(particles * ratio)
print molecules_needed

oligo = float(get_input("Conc. of your oligo?: "))
oligo_num = float(oligo * multiple) # amount

G = get_input("Enter number of G in Oligo: ")

A = get_input("Enter number of A in Oligo: ")

T = get_input("Enter number of T in Oligo: ")

C = get_input("Enter number of C in Oligo: ")

sumG = (G * 329)
sumA = (A * 313)
sumT = (T * 304)
sumC = (C * 289)
daoligo = (sumG + sumA + sumT + sumC) # g/mol

print "Total amount of your insert %s" % daoligo

oligototal = float(oligo_num / (daoligo/Avo)) # molecules for insert
complete = float(molecules_needed/oligototal) #amount of insert needed from stock ul

m = """
    What dilution will you use?
    1. Stock
    2. 1:10
    3. 1:20
    4. 1:30
    5. 1:50
    """

code = float(raw_input())
code =  get_input(m)

if code == 1:
    print complete #stock
elif code == 2:
    code2 = (oligototal/10)
    complete1 = float(molecules_needed/code2)
    print complete1 #1:10
elif code == 3:
    code3 = (oligototal/20)
    complete2 = float(molecules_needed/code3)
    print complete2 #1:20
elif code == 4:
    code4 = (oligototal/30)
    complete3 = float(molecules_needed/code4)
    print complete3 #1:30
elif code == 5:
    code_5 = (oligototal/50)
    complete4 = float(molecules_needed/code_5)
    print complete4
```

**Output**

```
Please put the amount of BPs: 
12
Put in Concentration (ng/ul): 
1
Amount of molecules:  76035353535.4
Amount of ul used by the plasmid: 
2
What ratio amount will you use?: 
3
4.56212121212e+11
Conc. of your oligo?: 
4
Enter number of G in Oligo: 
4
Enter number of A in Oligo: 
6
Enter number of T in Oligo: 
7
Enter number of C in Oligo: 
8
Total amount of your insert 7634
9

    What dilution will you use?
    1. Stock
    2. 1:10
    3. 1:20
    4. 1:30
    5. 1:50

1
1.44583333333
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some valid points in the other answer but it doesn't address all problems with the code. I have a few additions to make it cleaner IMO

1. Make it work for both `python3` and `python2`.
2. use a [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) body.
3. Added a dictionary to map the `code` (no more need for an `if else` block)
4. According to the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), functions and variables should be `snake_case`

---

```
def get_input(msg):
    return float(raw_input(msg))

def main():
    number = get_input("Please put the amount of BPs: ")
    solution = (number * 660)
    avo = (6.022 * (10 ** 23))
    grams_avo = ( solution / avo)

    conc = float(get_input("Put in Concentration (ng/ul): "))
    multiple = (10 ** -9)
    amount = (conc * multiple)
    total = float(amount / grams_avo)
    print ("Amount of molecules: {}".format(total))

    plasmid = float(get_input("Amount of ul used by the plasmid: "))
    particles = float(plasmid * total)

    ratio = get_input("What ratio amount will you use?: ")
    molecules_needed = float(particles * ratio)
    print (molecules_needed)

    oligo = float(get_input("Conc. of your oligo?: "))
    oligo_num = float(oligo * multiple)

    G = get_input("Enter number of G in Oligo: ")
    A = get_input("Enter number of A in Oligo: ")
    T = get_input("Enter number of T in Oligo: ")
    C = get_input("Enter number of C in Oligo: ")

    sum_G = (G * 329)
    sum_A = (A * 313)
    sum_T = (T * 304)
    sum_C = (C * 289)
    daoligo = (sum_G + sum_A + sum_T + sum_C)

    print ("Total amount of your insert {}".format(daoligo))

    oligototal = float(oligo_num / (daoligo/ avo))
    complete = float(molecules_needed/oligototal)

    m = """
What dilution will you use?
1. Stock
2. 1:10
3. 1:20
4. 1:30
5. 1:50
"""

    code = get_input(m)
    code_dict = {1: 1, 2: 10, 3: 20, 4: 30, 5: 50}
    print (float(molecules_needed/code_dict[code]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Cheat way to make input work in both Python3 and Python2
    try:
        raw_input = input
    except NameError:
        pass

    main()
```